# Fatal error: Call to undefined method ModelExtensionExtension::getExtensions()

Tags: opencart, fatal-error, opencart2.x

I have read the other undefined method questions and tried to apply the suggestions to my error with no luck. The full error is

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method ModelExtensionExtension::getExtensions() in     /home/*user*/public_html/*domain*/system/storage/modification/catalog/controller/common/header.php on line 9
```

Here is the code, line 9 is: $analytics = $this->model_extension_extension->getExtensions('analytics');

```
<?php
class ControllerCommonHeader extends Controller {
public function index() {
    // Analytics
    $this->load->model('extension/extension');

    $data['analytics'] = array();

    $analytics = $this->model_extension_extension->getExtensions('analytics');

    foreach ($analytics as $analytic) {
        if ($this->config->get($analytic['code'] . '_status')) {
            $data['analytics'][] = $this->load->controller('analytics/' . $analytic['code']);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have `getExtensions` in this file: `catalog/model/extension/extension.php` ?

Comment: Kindly define the version of using opencart

Comment: I am using 2.2.0.1 . For now i just block commented out that section of code /* */ And other errors popped up in it's place. As far as catalog/model/extension/extension.php this is all I have
    

 <?php
class ModelExtensionExtension extends Model {
 function getExtensions($type) {
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "extension WHERE `type` = '" . $this->db->escape($type) . "'");

  return $query->rows;
 }
}

Comment: Opencart 2.0 $this->redirect() has been changed to $this->response->redirect()

Comment: I didn't upgrade from an older version. These are the 2.2.0.1 files. When I add "->response" i get undefined variable "response" errors instead.

Answer (score 0):

This problem referrer to config.php file.

Verify that your CATALOG and MODIFICATION dir is correct.

In my case I solved this problem fixing this paths.